# Стоит ли писать однострочники на Python?

Tags: python

Начал изучать python, и вот возник вопрос, **стоит ли стараться писать код в одну строку**? В пример привёл два кода, оба работают одинаково, но как по мне второй писать и читать легче.

```
    print({i: i * i for i in range(1, 20) if not i % 2})
```

---

```
    res = {}
    for i in range(1, 20):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            res.setdefault(i, i * i)
    print(res)
```

Comment: посмотрите ещё много буков https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52542742/why-is-this-loop-faster-than-a-dictionary-comprehension-for-creating-a-dictionar

Comment: В данном примере первый код читать проще, да и запись проще, а если в целом, то порой встречаются ТАКИЕ однострочники, что мозг сломаешь пока разберёшься.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что два приведенных вами кода работают _не одинаково_ в смысле эффективности. Вот вы бы взяли и замерили скорость выполнения обоих кодов. Надо отличать рефакторинг от оптимизации, иногда это практически одно и тоже, а иногда две очень большие разницы.

Answer (score 5):

Такие вопросы отпадут сами собой, когда придется исправлять/дополнять свой код, написанный несколько лет назад.

Я не вижу ни одной причины писать в одну строку в реальных программах, которые будут использоваться более одного раза.

Для соревнований, в бумажных черновиках и для одноразовых скриптов запись в одну строку нормальна.

Comment: А некоторые очень уважаемые программисты на питоне утверждают, что писать однострочники хорошо, потому что несложный однострочник упрощает понимание кода.

Comment: @Глеб *А некоторые очень уважаемые программисты на питоне утверждают, что писать однострочники плохо, потому что сложный однострочник усложняет понимание кода* )) Однострочник однострочнику рознь, но в целом, если это что-то, что можно заменить на вызов метода (т.е. еще лаконичнее, чем однострочник), то стоит это сделать, а в методе уже нормально расписать (и юнит-тестами снабдить).

Answer (score 3):

Простые алгоритмы можно и нужно записывать сокращено, но только чтобы код был читаем